# Will anacron backup interfere with automatic fsck diskcheck on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, cron, fsck

I have a general question. I have a backup scheduled every day to back up my home folder and postgresql database to an external hard drive (file type ext4). The mount point of my external hard drive is /dev/sdb1. I ran the following command to schedule a disk check every 15 th boot.

```
sudo tune2fs -c 15 /dev/sdb1
```

Usually the system runs the backup script 5 minutes or so from startup. What I am worried about is that the disk check may occur during the backup and thus corrupt the external hard drive. Does the system (anacron) take this into account? If not, what can I do to achieve the desired outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am worried about is that the disk check may occur during the backup and thus corrupt the external hard drive.

No, the check cannot occur during the backup.

Your backup solution needs the filesystem on the external drive to be mounted, right? Even more: mounted with write access (not read-only). When targeted at ext4 filesystem, `fsck` means `fsck.ext4` which should be the same as (usually a symlink to) `e2fsck`. `e2fsck` will refuse to run on a mounted filesystem.

Additionally what you set with `tune2fs -c 15` may not trigger any automatic `fsck` at all. If your external drive is not mounted strictly at boot (e.g. via `/etc/fstab` or semi-equivalent systemd mechanism) then it's possible no `fsck` will be run, unless manually. Upon mounting (later, after boot) you may or may not see a message like:

```
warning: maximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is recommended
```

Compare [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/164384/108618). Note even if the filesystem is specified in `fstab`, you need a proper value in the sixth field to enable automatic `fsck`.

So the occurrence of automatic `fsck` really depends on how you mount the filesystem. If `fsck` is about to run automatically, it will be run before the filesystem is mounted.

Anyway `fsck.ext4` (a.k.a. `e2fsck`), automatic or not, will refuse to run if the filesystem is mounted.

Comment: Thanks Kamil for the detailed elaboration.